# Scope of require_once and objects

Tags: php, session, scope

Fairly new to PHP and still trying to wrap my head around scope issues that are cropping up.

Some suedo code:

This file is included from the index.php in the root.

login.php:

```
require_once("initialize.php");
//Get the $_POST data from the form submission.
//Call on the user object
User::createNewUser($firstName,$lastName,$email1,$password1);

//HTML
<form>signin stuff</form>
```

initialize.php:

```
//Define some path defaults for the site. 
//Load up some scripts.
require_once("session.php");
require_once("user.php");
//and several others
```

session.php:

```
class Session...
public $user;
public function login...
$session=new Session()
```

user.php:

```
class User...
public static function authenticate($email,$password){...
$session->login($user); //Here is the problem, $session is not defined.
```

So for some reason $session is not defined in User->authenticate yet if I do a var_dump at the top of user.php before the class it states that it is defined.

Is this enough to go on? Why is $session not defined when clearly it is.

This is the error that I get
 Notice: Undefined variable: session in D:\Program Files\wamp\www\site\application\controllers\user.php on line 55

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: That statement is inside a method, so the `$session` refers to a local variable, unless you say otherwise. You can say otherwise by either refering to a variable in global scope (very ugly and insecure) or by handing the variable over, either to the method itself or to the object you instantiate from the class to use the method. Very elegant would be a singleton class for the session with a static getter so that you can refer to the session object from wherever you want without having to place it in the global scope.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at so I'm looking up some of what you just said. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it "very ugly and insecure" to have it in global scope?And what is a "singleton class"?

Comment: "Ugly and insecure" because of what is called the "polution of the global name space". Imagine you have a project where you use two libraries. Now you and also the libraries all declare variables in global scope. That can easily lead to name collisions which you cannot even detect easily in php. So you end up overwriting each others values! A "singleton class" is a class that implements the "singleton pattern", one of the many well known programming patterns, so returning implementation strategies well tested and known to work. You will easily find an explanation on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use $session within a class method which would only have a scope local to that method.

The php manual covers this well: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

What you can do, is initialise the $session as a global variable and then you can access that from within your authenticate method.

Alternatively you could pass $session in as a parameter to your authenticate method.

For Example:

```
->authenticate($email,$password,$session);
```

Comment: I'm a bone head. PHP deals with scope in a way that I'm not used to. All I needed was to include 

global $session

in my function. I keep forgetting that one simple thing.